# Foil PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object

Tags: php

I'm using Foil PHP for the first time.
I've read all the documentation, but defining sections bring me this error:
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object

I've also tried exactly the example in the doc (http://www.foilphp.it/docs/TEMPLATES/INHERITANCE.html)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php $this->section('head') ?>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
          <title><?php $this->section('title') ?>My Home Page<?php $this->stop() ?></title>
        <?php $this->stop() ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
          <?php $this->section('content') ?>
          <?php $this->stop() ?>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
          <?php $this->section('footer') ?>
            &copy; Copyright 2014 by <a href="http://example.com/">you</a>.
          <?php $this->stop() ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

but it gave me the $this context fatal error.
Using $engine->render to render a template filled with html content works.

Please help me :(

Comment: Did you install all the necessary libraries/classes for this?

Comment: I've used composer so yes it has downloaded all the 4 required library.

Comment: Better check your install/paths then, it could be that. Or, see the answer below. If that doesn't solve the question, you may have to post more (if relevant) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you accessing this directly? That won't work. $this only works INSIDE a class:

```
<?php

class Thing
{
    private $x;

   public function getValue()
   {
        return $this->x;
   }
}
```

You should be rendering your template from the engine.

Comment: Sorry but in the documentation is not like that, templates are php files not php classes, and the rendering is made through the engine but if I render a template, so a php file, with a section or block definition (with $this->section('name') ) than I have the fatal error

Comment: Ok I really can't understand but now it works.

Comment: @Dany92 how did you make it works?